# delete from and to cursor in "nano"

Tags: nano

I use nano, and I want to use control + k and control + u to delete to and from the cursor how it is in the regular shell, but they have different functions in nano by default.

1 - Does nano have a shortcut to delete everything before the cursor on line a line and another for everything after the cursor?

2 - Can I make my own shortcut for it in my nanorc and be control + k and control + u? If so, how? I've previously changed my tab to 4 spaces in nanorc so I know I can do some work there; so wondering if I can do that too.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Answering to the first part of the question.

M-T (Alt T consecutively, not at the same time)   Cut from the cursor position to the end of the file.
Not aware about command to cut everything to the left, but these may help:
Alt+Bsp     Delete word to the left
Ctrl+Del    Delete word to the right

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You can delete a line, a word before/after, but not to the beginning/end of line. Anyway, all default shortcuts are here:
   https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/cheatsheet.html
2. Yes, but it is fairly new ability. Some distributive have older versions of `nano` so it is not guaranty you would be able to, but if your `nano` is a modern one, go to `~/.nanorc` and add something like

```
bind ^S savefile main
unbind ^W writeout main
```

Full documentation is here: https://nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html#Rebinding-Keys